# php mysql join two tables to join some column and union some column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

i need your help

I have searched for the same question on this website but I did not find it.

So, I have several tables.

for example :

table `male`:

```
+------+------+------------+--------+
|  id  | name |    date    |  point |
+-----------------------------------+
|  32  | john | 2017-20-01 |  5000  |
|  47  | mike | 2019-08-02 |  2000  |
|  49  | luiz | 2019-01-02 |  2700  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

table `female`:

```
+------+------+------------+--------+
|  id  | name |    date    |  point |
+-----------------------------------+
|  12  | lisa | 2018-03-05 |  3000  |
|  16  | jane | 2018-08-22 |  2000  |
|  49  | Sisi | 2018-12-30 |  2000  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I want to join the two tables above to be:

```
+------+------+------------+-----------+--------------+
|  id  | name |    date    | male-pont | female-point |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+
|  32  | john | 2017-20-01 |    5000   |      -       |
|  47  | mike | 2019-08-02 |    2000   |      -       |
|  49  | luiz | 2019-01-02 |    2700   |      -       |
|  12  | lisa | 2018-03-05 |     -     |     3000     |
|  16  | jane | 2018-08-22 |     -     |     2000     |
|  49  | Sisi | 2018-12-30 |     -     |     2000     |
+------+------+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

how to make it?
help me please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`. You just need to adjust the point columns:

```
select id, name, date, point male_point, null female_point from table_male
union all
select id, name, date, null, point from table_female
```

Note that this gives you a `null` value where no point value is available - instead of `-`, which is a string so would require datatype conversion.

Comment: excelent, it's work 100%

Comment: thank you very much